# Capture geolocation in XPages

Tags: xpages-ssjs

I want to capture the geo-location data of a web user and store it in a Notes document with server side javascript.

Since I know XPages does not have a control for detecting the geolocation and the CGI variables are helpfull neither.

How should I do this?

Comment: <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
  <xp:this.value>
   <![CDATA[$(document).ready(
 $.get('http://ipinfo.io', function (response) {
    $('#ip').html('IP: ' + response.ip);
    $('#address').html('Location: ' + response.city + ', ' + response.region);
    $('#details').html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
    x$( "#{id:inputText1}" ).val(response.city)
    
}, 'jsonp')
);
]]>
  </xp:this.value>
 </xp:scriptBlock>

Comment: but is not ready when loading the page...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the relevant parts of a script block I use to find the geo coordinates when a page loads. Works with WebKit browser I have tested on, but does not work with IE.

```
<xp:scriptBlock>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
var geo_location = {
    latitude : 0,
    longitude : 0,
    emsg : "",

    showLocation : function(position) {
        geo_location.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        geo_location.longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        var prOptions = {"latitude" : geo_location.latitude, 
                        "longitude" : geo_location.longitude,
                        "msg" : geo_location.emsg};

        XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:geoLocationPanel}",
        {
            params : prOptions,
            onError : function () {
                alert("geoLocationPanel partialRefresh Error");
            }   
        });
    }
};

XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // function to get the current geo location
        try {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_location.showLocation);
        } catch (e) {
            geo_location.emsg = e.toString();
            alert("navigator.geolocation Error\n" + geo_location.emsg);
            geo_location.showLocation({
                coords : {
                    latitude : 0,
                    longitude : 0
                }
            })
        }
    }, 200);
}
)]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```